# Displaying total number of records in SQL in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to display the number of records I have in my database in PHP
This is the code I have at the moment

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($link,'tasks_db');

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM newtask");
printf ("TOTAL: %d\n", mysqli_fetch_array($result));
mysqli_query($link, "COMMIT");
?>
```

But it is just displaying one record and not the two I actually have in my database?  Not sure where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using SQL `count` aggregate function and get the column an alisa name.

Getting the `count`  number by alisa name in `mysqli_fetch_array`.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM newtask");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("TOTAL: %d\n", $row["cnt"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You sould use [COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) in SQL Query, for example:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) as number FROM pet;
+----------+
| number   |
+----------+
|        9 |
+----------+
```

In your case it might be:

```
SELECT count(*) as number FROM newtask
```

Comment: Hi Thanks,  but it still seems to only show 1 entry even if i add more?

Comment: Wha to do you mean? It will return only one row with one column called 'number' which should contain number of counted rows

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use:

```
SELECT count(id) as `total` FROM `newtask`
```

or

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `newtask` LIMIT 0, 10;
```

if you'd like to paginate the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf ("TOTAL: %d\n", mysqli_fetch_array($result));
```

mysqli_fetch_array is not enough to get the count because it only fetches the first row on the result set. Try this

`printf ("TOTAL: %d\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));`

Answer (score 0):

you use this code also show rows as result.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM newtask");
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
printf ("TOTAL: %d\n", $numrows);
```